# Programatically adding escape characters to Python List

Tags: python, graphql, escaping

I have a Python list:

```
instrumentList=["44433141537", "192797680391", "192773331481", "44433141641", "44434295873"]
```

I want to write this list to a text file and escape the " characters. The final output I am looking for is:

```
[\"44433141537\", \"192797680391\", \"192773331481\", \"44433141641\", \"44434295873\"]
```

This string will ultimately end up being concatenated between two further [static] strings that I have manual escaped - the overall string is a graphQL query that is passed to a GraphQL API endpoint which needs quote marks and line feeds escaped.

I've tried:

```
escapedInstrumentList={json.dumps(instrumentList).replace("'","\'")}
```

but this outputs:

```
"[""44433141537"", ""192797680391"", ""192773331481"", ""44433141641"", ""44434295873""]"
```

Any guidance gratefully received.

Paul

Comment: `[\"44433141537\", \"192797680391\", \"192773331481\", \"44433141641\", \"44434295873\"]` - are you *sure* about this? Show more context, because in and of it self, this particular format does not seem to make a lot of sense.

Comment: Try `repr(instrumentList).replace("'", r"\'"))`

Comment: `fr'\"{"44433141537"}\"'` - `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert your list of strings to a string that can be printed to a text file you can use this:

```
instrumentList=["44433141537", "192797680391", "192773331481", "44433141641", "44434295873"]

output = '['+ ', '.join([f'\\"{item}\\"' for item in instrumentList]) + ']'

print(output)
```

Output as requirement.

Comment: This method gives me the best results for what I'm trying to achieve, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
instrumentList=["44433141537", "192797680391", "192773331481", "44433141641", "44434295873"]
json.dumps(instrumentList).replace('"', '''\\"''')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json, re
instrumentList=["44433141537", "192797680391", "192773331481", "44433141641", "44434295873"]
escapedInstrumentList= {re.sub('"', '/"', json.dumps(instrumentList)) }
print(escapedInstrumentList)
```

Try this one.